# Nvidia 304 Driver support in 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I'm currently on 12.04.4 and getting the upgrade prompt for 14.04 LTS. Just wondering if the Nvidia 304 drivers are supported. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to know weather `nvidia-304` is in 14.04?

Comment: Yes, Nvidia drivers are supported, and the [304 driver](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-304) is also in the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

See [Mike's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502890/nvidia-304-driver-support-in-14-04-1#comment675793_502890): Yes, Nvidia drivers are supported, and the 304 driver is also in the repositories.